# count occurrences of values in a string row

Tags: c#, php, excel, count

I have a row like this:   a a b b b a b a a b b
I need code to print this out: 2a 3b 1a 1b 2a 2b

How to do that in c#

EDIT
I need the values to be counted like this: there are 2 of a then 3 of b then 1 of a then 1 of b then 2 of a then 2 of b.
I don't need to count occurrences of a and b in total.

I am reading a matrix, value by value diagonally:
If I have matrix like this:

```
 a a b a
 a b a b
 a b b a
```

I managed to read matrix from the bottom right corner - up and to put values in rows:

```
1row: a
2row: bb
3row: baa
4row: bba
5row: aa
6row: a
```

But I need this to look like this:

```
1row: 1a
2row: 2b
3row: 1b2a
4row: 2b1a
5row: 2a
6row: 1a
```

Comment: C# and php? What have you tried?

Comment: What are your requirements? Like, what are the conditions how `2a 3b 1a 2b 2a 2b` is created.

Comment: it suppose to count the occurrences  like this: there are 2 of a, then 3 of b then 1a , then 2 of b ...

Comment: *Any* language? Sounds you want us to do your work. Maybe someone out there that can do that for me just because he/she is so nice? Anyway. maybe there is someone who can give you in a language like D or some other weird ones that you won´t understand.

Comment: Seems like you should have a look on [run-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding)

Comment: @HimBromBeere thank you, yes that what I need, but I didn't know to name it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a RegEx approach

```
string input = "aabbbabaabb";
string result = string.Concat(Regex.Matches(input, @"(.)\1*", RegexOptions.None)
                      .Cast<Match>()
                      .Select(x => string.Concat(x.Length, x.Value.First())));
```

Comment: yes it is,tnx anyway.